# Can't download files with chrome headless with Selenium Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

Chrome is not downloading any file when runned in headless mode! It was working perfectly fine till last week! Suddenly it started to fail! I've tried with different OS, different Selenium version, still no luck!

It does download on my computer, but not on Github Actions and AWS!

Have a look at My setup:

```
HashMap<String, Object> headlessChromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            ChromeOptions headlessChromeOption = new ChromeOptions();
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            headlessChromeOption.addArguments("--headless=new");
            headlessChromeOption.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            headlessChromeOption.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            headlessChromeOption.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            headlessChromeOption.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1200");
            headlessChromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadDirectory);
            headlessChromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            headlessChromeOption.setExperimentalOption("prefs", headlessChromePrefs);
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, headlessChromeOption);
            headlessChromeOption.merge(capabilities);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(headlessChromeOption);
```

Environment:
Java 11, Selenium 4.4.0

Please help me find the issue! Thanks team!!

Comment: Please share more of your code, need to see the part where file is (should be) downloaded. Add the code output as well.

Comment: @pburgr it just clicks on download button which downloads a file! I've not written code to read or write bytes for downloading! Just want to download file via browser like usual! please let me know if these were the details you are asking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for downloading failure was screen size on cloud! I was able to resolve it by:

1. For java instead of ***--window-size=1920,1080***
   I did:

`driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));`

2. Now I'm running selenium with xvfb!

UPDATE: Above solution works with sequential execution but not with parallel